# C++ code not running as it should be

Tags: c++

Here is my C++ code for counting sort algorithm , there is no errors as well as no warnings but when I want to execute it it's give me "Counting.exe has stopped working" I think it is a run time error.

```
void Counting_sort()
{
    int A[]={5,15,20,30,40,8,36,25,96,15,40,15,96,47,20};
    int k = 15 ; 
    int n = 15;
    int i, j;
    int B[15];
    int C[100];
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i++)
        C[i] = 0;
    for(j =1; j <= n; j++)
        C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1];
    for(j = n; j >= 1; j--)
    {
        B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
        C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] - 1;
    }
    cout << "\nThe Sorted array is : ";
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cout << B[i] << " " ;
} 

void main()
{

    Counting_sort();
}
```

Comment: You read out of bounds of the `A` array, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn some basic debugging skills - step through the code in your debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: `// Using comments would definitely improve the readability of your code`

Comment: I ran the code in my debugger and it immediately stopped at the line causing the error.

Comment: And what line would that be?

Comment: Use `std::vector` and use `my_vector.at(i)` instead of `my_vector[i]` to avoid this kind of mistake. Once you are (very!) confident that you won't make that mistake anymore, replace the occurences of `at` with the subscript operator for better performance.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Are you asking me? It's `C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1;`

Answer (score 4):

```
for(j = n; j >= 1; j--)
{
  // You are accessing A[j]
}
```

So `A[15]` is a invalid access and will lead to undefined behavior.
The valid access for array `A[15]` is `A[0]` to `A[14]` anything other than this is array out of bound access.

Comment: Haven't read the code but for the OP, is changing `>=` to `>` the solution for that problem?

Comment: @EvanCarslake Read the code..

Comment: @Gopi , i am beginner here and this is a task at university so please i want more explanation and how my code will be can you answer please

Comment: @user2780962 I have answered your question. Very clearly you need to access the arrays within bound else you are bound to hit with issues

Comment: The first thing is you have to learn that c++ uses 0 based indexing of arrays. Meaning if you have a 15 element array the valid indices are 0 through 14. 15 is out of bounds. Although @Gopi said that in the answer above.

Comment: @Gopi please can you edit my code piece to become correct code

Comment: Here's a suggestion - you edit it.